# How to WKWebView swift Javascript enable

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, wkwebview

I am using WKWebView to load some links in my application. I want to enable all JavaScript banners that appear on most web pages. Currently when I open the WebView I cannot manipulate the button in the webView.

I tried to enable all javascript like below code but it still not working.

My current configuration is IOS 14, I want it to work on all profiles

```
func setupWebView() {
        let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        configuration.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
        if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
            let webPageDefaultPrefs = WKWebpagePreferences()
            webPageDefaultPrefs.allowsContentJavaScript = true
            configuration.defaultWebpagePreferences = webPageDefaultPrefs
        } else {
            let preferences = WKPreferences()
            preferences.javaScriptEnabled = true
            configuration.preferences = preferences
        }
        let webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: configuration)
        self.webView = webView
    }
```